# Very basic question

Tags: functions

Would this be a valid function or not, even though it's repeating itself? (I'm referring to the t=3)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "valid function"? It indeed is a function...

Comment: Well, because it was repeating itself I wasn't sure if this was correct or not...

Comment: How do you mean by repeating itself? $sin(x)$ repeats itself and is a function. It's not a bijective function however.

Comment: Well, I mean that the instructions were saying the samething at t=3

Comment: In the future, please try to use a more descriptive subject for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Abstractly, a function must assign a unique value in its codomain to every element in the domain. So, for any $t \in [0,6]$, you have a unique value assigned.

Some people prefer not to have this over-specification, but really it's a notational preference rather than a true mathematical concept.

Comment: I would say it is bad form to have both lines tell you what the value at $t=3$ is, but as long as they agree it is still a function.  In essence by calling it a function you promise the reader that it doesn't matter which line is taken when more than one applies.

Answer (score 2):

If $V3 = V(6-3)$, then this function is well-defined.  (It takes only one value on the input $3$ and on any other input.)  Otherwise, not.

Answer (score 0):

$f(3)$ is defined because it has the unique value $3V$ using either of the definitions at 3. But I don't think it's a good practice to double define it. One of them shouldn't have an equality.